# How to let sbt fail directly if the calling task is failed?

Tags: shell, sbt

In a shell file, I invoke a sbt task to do something, and then do some other things.

But I found `sbt` will block the shell if the task is failed, and sbt will waiting for answer:

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Is there any way to just let sbt fail? Because the shell file is running on CI, it will block it forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sbt` supports `-batch` which can solve this problem:

```
sbt -batch
```

Comment: Not super convenient(some config would be better) but it does the trick!